# How to add texture from android to unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I know I can get it with Unity with these lines:

```
Texture2D texture = Resources.Load ("TextureTest") as Texture2D; 
GameObject obPlane  = GameObject.Find("Plane");
obPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture = texture ;
```

But it's not my goal. I want to do it from Android to Unity.

I've tried (in Java):

```
private boolean updateTexture(int IDTexture) {

Bitmap b = getBitMapFromFile("sample.bmp");
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, IDTexture);;
ByteBuffer bf = extract(b);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bf);
return true;

}
```

And in Unity I get the textureID with cTexture.GetNativeTextureID():

```
void Start () {

   cTexture = new Texture2D (width, height,TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
   cTexture.Apply();
   obPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture = cTexture;

}

if(GUI.Button(new Rect(a,b,c,c), "Button")) {

 activity.Call("updateTexture", cTexture.GetNativeTextureID());          
}
```

But when I press the button, nothing happens.

Comment: were you able to solve your issue? Looking for similar thing but can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

A few things to remember when doing texturing with plugins:

- Any time something alters Unity's graphical state externally, these alterations must be performed from the same thread as the renderer runs on. This means that your calling function should originate in one of the graphical Monobehaviour methods such as `OnPreRender()` and `OnPreCull()` to name but a few. I cant find an explicit list in the docs, but it should be easy enough to work out which are relevant. [MonoBehaviour Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) The script that these calls are performed from must also be attached to the main camera in the scene.
- Any time the graphical state of the engine is altered externally (like you are doing here) you must call `GL.InvalidateState()` afterwards. The docs explain this well:

*"This invalidates any cached renderstates tied to the GL context. If for example a (native) plugin alters the renderstate settings then Unity's rendering architecture must be made aware of that to not assume the GL context is preserved."* - [GL.InvaliateState Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/ScriptReference/GL.InvalidateState.html)

**Slightly off topic**

Let me also add that I attempted something identical to you, and failed to get the texture to update at all. While I'm not sure why this is the case, i can provide a much less efficient, but working method if speed is not critical. If you do get this working, please let me know on the question I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642503/trying-to-set-a-texture-from-java-plugin-in-unity-4-6), I'll be sure to update this answer if i find a proper solution.

This method will take in a bitmap from a path, scale and/or compress it (Unity has a max texture size of 4096x4096) into a byte array, which Unity then reads into a texture.

```
byte[] m_image; 
File inFile = new File(_fileName);
Bitmap bm;
int width, height;
height = width = 4096;
String logTag = "BitmapHandler";

//Use BitmapFactory to check that bitmap is not too large.
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(inFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

m_StartWidth = options.outWidth;
m_StartHeight = options.outHeight;

//If it is, calculate a sampleSize to reduce the image by
if (options.outWidth > 4096 || options.outHeight > 4096) {
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 4096, 4096);
}
else {
    width = options.outWidth;
    height = options.outHeight;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
}
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_fileName, options);

try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    m_image = out.toByteArray();
    m_width = bm.getWidth();
    m_height = bm.getHeight();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    m_image = null;
    m_height = -1;
    m_width = -1;
    return null;
}
return m_image;
```

How sample size is worked out - scales the image by a power of two so that both width and height are smaller than 4096 pixels:

```
private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        while (height / inSampleSize > reqHeight || width / inSampleSize > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *=2;
        }
    }
return inSampleSize;
}
```

I'm sorry that I can't directly solve the problem, but i hope that the info I've given will be of use to you!