# Trying to set a texture from Java plugin in Unity 4.6

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

**What i'm trying to do:**

- Pull an image from sd-card on phone using Java Plugin.
- Unity passes a texture ID to plugin.
- Plugin uses opengl to assign the image to the texture in Unity through the ID.
- Will (eventually) be used to play a video clip from the phone in Unity, for now, it's just trying to change a texture outside of unity.

**My issue:**

When i call the method in the plugin, passing `texture.GetNativeTextureID()` into it, the texture does not change. I'm currently only using a simple black 50x50 texture for testing, and the original texture is a flat white.

I'm worried that i've missed something significant, as this is my first time working with Gl calls in java. Much of the answers to similar problems involve using native C++ instead of Java, but I can't find a concrete answer saying that C++ **must** be used. I'd like to do my best to avoid writing another set of plugins and plugin handlers for C++, but if it's the most efficient/only way to get this working, i'll do it as i'm not unfamiliar with OpenGL and C++

**Code:**

The plugin method is called from `OnPreRender()` in a script attached to the main camera:

```
if (grabTex) {
    int texPtr = m_VideoTex.GetNativeTextureID();
    Debug.Log( "texPtr = " + texPtr );
    m_JVInterface.SetTex( texPtr );
}
```

`m_VideoTex` is a basic `Texture2D( 50, 50 )` with all pixels set to white, attached to the diffuse shader on the quad in the scene.

The Java plugin code is as follows:

```
public void SetTexture(Context cont, int _texPointer) {
    if (_texPointer != 0) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/black.jpg", options);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texPointer);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        Log.i("VideoHandler", "Recieved ID: " + _texPointer);

        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with the OpenGL Context. The easiest way would be to send the texture as raw bytes to Unity and then upload as texture inside Unity.